# Creating Regex grouping of "OR" conditions to shorten an expression

Tags: python, regex, string, regex-lookarounds, string-matching

I am capturing a string that is being passed in a text message. The condition is based on the word "contact".

Here are three sample texts:

```
ntpd process is not running on lnx31 contact: app-support. @monitoringautomation
ntpd process is not running on lnx31 contact: app-support, @monitoringautomation
ntpd process is not running on lnx31 contact app-support @monitoringautomation
```

My current regex is:

```
/(?i)contact:* (\S+),|(?i)contact:* (\S+)\.|(?i)contact:* (\S+)\s*/gm
```

My question, is there another way to clean this expression up or to shorten it? I have tried the following example, but it does not capture the app team when a period or comma is used, it includes it in the match.

```
/((?i)contact:* (\S+)(,|\.|\s*))/gm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?i)\bcontact:*\s*([^,.\s]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CQu175/1).

*Details*:

- `(?i)` - case insensitive inline modifier option
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `contact` - a string `contact`
- `:*` - zero or more colons
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `([^,.\s]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than whitespace, comma and period.

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/DO8dZt):

```py
import re
text = """ntpd process is not running on lnx31 contact: app-support. @monitoringautomation
ntpd process is not running on lnx31 contact: app-support, @monitoringautomation
ntpd process is not running on lnx31 contact app-support @monitoringautomation"""
print( re.findall(r"(?i)\bcontact:*\s*([^,.\s]+)", text) )
# => ['app-support', 'app-support', 'app-support']
```